# Appropriate algorithm to find all the transitive closure loops in graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, transitive-closure

I want to find all the transitive closure loops in my graph having following conditions:

1. if all nodes present in identified loop is a sub set of another identified loop, then we will consider superset only.
2. find all distinct loops.

NOTE: read "loop" as-->  transitive closure loop (i..e nodes in transitive closure  set)

Comment: From your description it sounds like you are looking for an algorithm for finding [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) for transitive part only, then check for any reflexive loops since transitive loops would be represented as reflexive loops in the end.